# Implementation of pipe in C

Tags: c, linux, unix

I just finished my shell interpretor but I think my pipe implementation is wrong.

It's working, basic things like `ls | cat -e` works but I am afraid of `segmentation fault` possibilities if the file descriptor is over 60 ko.
I found also a infinite loop when I do a cat of a file which is longer than 60 ko. For exemple if a do a cat `foo | cat -e` where foo is a long file, infinite loop happen.

Or other exemple when I do `cat /dev/urandom | cat -e` it don't show me any display so it execute first `cat /dev/urandom` and then `cat -e`.

This is my code :

```
int son(int *fd_in, int p[2], t_list *cmd, char **env)
{
    (void)env;
    dup2(*fd_in, 0);
    if (cmd->act != ENDACT && cmd->act != LEFT && cmd->act != DLEFT)
        dup2(p[1], 1);
    close(p[0]);
    execve(cmd->av[0], cmd->av, NULL);
    return (-1);
}

t_list *execute_pipe(t_list *cmd, int *fd_in)
{
    int           p[2];
    pid_t         pid;

    *fd_in = 0;
    while (cmd->act != -1)
    {
        pipe(p);
        if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
            return (NULL);
        else if (pid == 0)
            son(fd_in, p, cmd, NULL);
        else
        {
            wait(NULL);
            close(p[1]);
            *fd_in = p[0];
            if (cmd->act != PIPE)
                return (cmd);
            cmd = cmd->next;
        }
    }
    return (cmd);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, how to do the pipe the right way. Because how I do it now is wrong.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~mamrak/CIS762/pipes_lab_notes.html

Comment: @trigger, the question has nothing to do with batch files.  It was just mis-tagged.

Comment: My point. Unix people have ton stop tagging things Windows.

Comment: @trigger, people "have to" stop tagging C++ questions as C, too.  And they "have to" stop tagging Java questions as Javascript.  And so forth.  By and large, mistags happen because the OP doesn't understand what the tags mean, and therefore *it will never stop*.  Your life will be more fulfilling if you just get over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of the idea of a shell pipeline is that the processes involved run concurrently (or may do).  The code you presented actively prevents that from happening by `wait()`ing on each child process before launching the next one.  Among other things, that runs the risk of filling the (OS-level) pipe's buffer before there's anything ready to drain it.  That will deadlock or, if you're lucky, generate an error.

At a high level, the procedure should look like this:

1. **[shell]** Let `C` initially be the command for the first segment of the pipe, and set `fd0` to be `STDIN_FILENO`
2. **[shell]** Prepare an output file descriptor:

   1. If there are any subsequent commands, create a `pipe()`, and set `fd1` to be the write end of that pipe;
   2. otherwise, set `fd1` to be `STDOUT_FILENO`
3. **[shell]** `fork()` a child in which to run command `C`.  In it:

   1. **[child]** if `fd0` is different from `STDIN_FILENO` then `dup2()` `fd0` onto `STDIN_FILENO` and close `fd0`
   2. **[child]** if `fd1` is different from `STDOUT_FILENO` then `dup2()` `fd1` onto `STDOUT_FILENO` and close `fd1`
   3. **[child]** exec command `C`
4. **[shell]** if `fd0` is different from `STDIN_FILENO` then close `fd0`
5. **[shell]** if `fd1` is different from `STDOUT_FILENO` then close `fd1`
6. **[shell]** If there are any more commands in the pipe, then

   1. set `C` to be the next command
   2. set `fd0` to be the read end of the pipe from step (2), above
   3. go to step 2 (Prepare an output file descriptor)
7. **[shell]** (At this point, all processes in the pipeline have been started.)  `wait()` or `waitpid()` for all the child processes

Note that that works equally well for a pipeline containing any positive number of commands, including 1.

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! So as I understood, you are telling me that I should stop waiting for the child process ? That should cause a lot of problems no ? Like a process can finish before the other one or something like that.

Comment: You must wait for each child process, but only after all of them have been started (step 7 in my answer).  It is the *user's* problem to provide appropriate commands for each segment of the pipeline.  Typical commands used in such context will not exit until their standard input is closed.  If a process does exit before consuming all the data from a previous one in the pipe then a broken pipe results.  This can and sometimes does happen with the standard shells.  Your shell can be made to handle it with either more or less grace.

Comment: The procedure looks reasonable but the explanation at top does not match (and doesn't make sense). You don't "wait on each child process before launching the next one" (indeed your comment above notes that you only wait after all are launched. Also, a full pipe cannot cause a deadlock or an error (barring some extraordinary - and intentional - situation). As pipe(7) notes, a full pipe will simply block the writer (unless O_NONBLOCK is set which is a special case that programs wanting that behavior will handle properly).

Comment: @GilHamilton, the comments at the top describe issues with the code presented by the OP, not recommendations for how the job should be done.  I have updated my answer to clarify.  As for deadlock, the OP's code suffers from the possibility that one child is blocked writing to a pipe, while creation of another to drain that pipe is blocked on completion of the first.  Neither can progress without the other first doing so -- that's deadlock.  Or at least, that's what I meant by the term.  You may prefer a different one.

Comment: Ah. Ok. That makes sense now.